# jQuery Plugin Autocomplete Fade In List

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, plugins

I have successfully implement the [jQuery Autocomplete plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) into my site, using the [examples](http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/) as a template.

However, I am looking to fade in the suggestion list in the autocomplete so its a smooth transition, rather than just suddenly appearing and disappearing as it currently does.

I have looked through the options, but cant see anything to will achieve what I'm looking for. Thanks

Comment: Just a note.  You may want to reconsider that approach.  It sounds like flaky UI cues to fade in an autocomplete.  IMHO, an autocomplete shouldn't be faded, but should instantly appear.

Comment: Just wanted a bit of a smoother approach....it seems a bit clunky the way it appears in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, there's an "extraParams" option that accepts a callback.

So you could probably pass a closure to extraParams that does that.